# Child web.config can't clear <pages><controls> from parent web.config

Tags: asp.net

How can I "clear" the vendor defined `<controls>` in my child app's web.config?

Parent Web Config.

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
             <!-- START: Vendor Custom Control -->
             <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="VENDOR.Web.UI.Base" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral />
             ...
             <!-- END: Vendor Custom Control -->
             ...
           </controls>
       <tagMapping>
         <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager" mappedTagType="Microsoft.Web.Preview.UI.Controls.WebParts.WebPartManager" />
         <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartZone" mappedTagType="Microsoft.Web.Preview.UI.Controls.WebParts.WebPartZone" />
       </tagMapping>
     </pages>
</system.web>
```

Child:

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </controls>
        <tagMapping>
            <clear/>
        </tagMapping>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

I have it working for the `<tagMapping>` section, but `<controls>` does not support `<clear/>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little known way of [stopping web.config inheritence](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/04/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html). In your case you would stick a `<location inheritInChildApplications="false">...</location>` around the `<system.web>...</system.web>` element. Of course this would remove the inheritance of everything in the section but it would solve your inheritance problem if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to add custom functionality to a Vendor's app.  I would prefer not to modify the parent web.config.  I might have to settle and pull the vendor's DLLs into my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<remove/>` for each tagprefix, possibly in conjunction with a  `<clear/>` at the top

Comment: `<remove/>` is not supported either. Error: 
The element 'controls' has invalid child element 'remove'. List of possible elements expected: 'add'.